# How to check if an SVN working copy contains a switched subdirectory

Tags: svn

I have an SVN working copy, of which I just discovered that in the past I switched a subdirectory (about three directories deep) to a different branch. I switched it back, but now I'm not sure whether there are still other subdirectories that may have been switched.

Is there a command that gives an overview of the status of switched subdirectories in a working copy? Possibly also including subdirectories that have been updated to a certain revision only, etc.

If possible in TortoiseSVN, but at least on the command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:

> have been updated to a certain revision only, etc

doesn't have a much sense. Did you try to detect just "Is my WC clean or not?", regardless of where and how it's dirty? Because different dirty-reasons require different detection methods (AFAICR)

Overview of status of WC is (surprise!!!) `svn status`. For switched dir (not for up to specific rev) it have

> ```
> ...
>     Fifth column: Whether the item is switched or a file external
>       ' ' normal
>       'S' the item has a Switched URL relative to the parent
>       'X' a versioned file created by an eXternals definition
> ...
> ```

"updated to a certain revision" subtree produces the usual (and normal for SVN) [mixed Working Copy](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs) and you haven't a *reliable method* of separation "mixed by need" from "mixed by mistake". "Check for modification" (with "Check repository" button) in TSVN will show you outdated (with revisions in repository newer, than in your WC) objects, but doesn't show nothing about reasons of this state

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at svn info. TortoiseSVN doesn't seem to show this status info clearly, but I'll look again into that with this knowledge. The bit about subdirectories "updated to a certain revision only" was a bit of an afterthought, not really what I needed right now. I'll wait a little bit to see if a better answer comes up, otherwise I will accept this one.

Comment: @gpvos - if these check are pre-build preparation and your final business task is "have clean WC for build and deploy", you can think about using subwcrev (part of TSVN, which you have)

Comment: I now finally notice that TortoiseSVN lists the switched directory as "normal (s)", with the "s" apparently meaning "switched". Subtle, but it's there. I had some problems with the wc and had to run cleanup, so I missed that. The business case was more like "what do I have on my computer and why?"